# Change checkbox design from square to circle

Tags: css, angular, checkbox, sass

Thank you for your help in advance.
I'm trying to change the mat-checkbox design from square to circle.
but is a little bit hard to find a way.

Can you help me??

I can change only the background with the code below.

```
mat-checkbox { 
  border-radius: 100%;
  color: rgb(0,178,0);
  /deep/ .mat-checkbox-background {
    background-color: rgb(0,178,0);
  }
  /deep/ &.mat-checkbox-focused {
    .mat-ink-ripple {
      background-color: rgba(0, 178, 0, .26);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bear in mind, by doing so the component will look more like a radio button than a checkbox, so may provide a bad user experience. That said, you can add a border radius to `mat-checkbox-frame` and `mat-checkbox-background`

```
/deep/ .mat-checkbox-frame,
/deep/ .mat-checkbox-background {
    border-radius: 50% !important;
}
```

You can also remove the `tick` effect with the following rules

```
/deep/ .mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background, 
/deep/ .mat-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
    margin: 4px;
}

/deep/ .mat-checkbox-background svg {
    display: none;
}
```

**[Here is an example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-with-angular-v5-exbxj8?file=app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: thanks!! but how can I change the checked effect?? from (v) to (o)?? Thank yo again

Comment: Ive just updated the answer and the example, is that what you wanted?

Comment: thank you very much. but Actually, I want to make the checkbox design looks like a radio button. when I checked the checkbox button it turns from (  ) -> ( v ). but I want to turns it from (   ) -> ( O ). Thank you!!!

Comment: Sorry, just updated again. Try that. Having said that, if you want a radio button surely it would be easier to use a radio button?

Comment: @이상현 If that solves your question, please mark the answer as accepted using the green tick button. That way, others with the same issue can find the solution. Thank you