# Checkbox checked button are not organized

Tags: html, css, checkbox, angular-material

I have some problem with a checkbox.

I have changed my checkbox design looks like a radio button.

I referred to this Q/A below.

[Change checkbox design from square to circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51996556/change-checkbox-design-from-square-to-circle)

but as you can see the image below.. is not organized well. looks very weird when I change Joom or use a different monitor.

there is any solution to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance!!

[image]

Comment: Could you paste code snippet so that it can be debugged better

Comment: Its working perfect in mentioned example. If you made any changes to that please mention code here. otherwise  ask in that same thread.

Comment: @Znaneswar Please don't ask in the same thread. Consider opening a new question.

Comment: @Edric i don't understand what do you mean?

Comment: hello, when you check the code below, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-with-angular-v5-5xp4og?file=app/app.component.ts I changed zoom and also have the same problem..